# python+ keras Error: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions

Tags: python, keras

I have DNA data as input to Keras, DNA data is an one-hot encoded array it such that each DNA sequence is 4 channels (one for each type of nucleotide). The one-hot matrix is in matlab and has the dimension: (4,400,100)  100 samples.

first matlab has dimensions row* cloumn * slice (4, 400, 100)
but I change dimensions to get  (100, 4, 400) like python format

```
    import scipy.io 
    x = scipy.io.loadmat('x.mat')
    x2 = x['x']
    x2 = np.ascontiguousarray(x2.T)
    x2 = np.ascontiguousarray(x2.swapaxes(1, 2))
    X_train =x2
    y = scipy.io.loadmat('y.mat')
    y2 = y['y']
    Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y2, 2)
```

Now the X_train shape is: (100, 4, 400)
Y_train shape is (100, 2)

2)

And my model is Conv1D looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(4, 400)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=10)
```

Error massage

```
Traceback (most recent call last): in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=5)

in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 2)
```

Comment: Could you add to your post the shape of Y_train, X_train?

Answer (score 0):

Try this version:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Dropout, Dense, Flatten

# This generates some test sample for me to check your code
X_train = np.random.rand(100, 4, 400)
Y_train = np.random.rand(100, 2)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(4, 400)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten()) # <- You need a flatten here
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')) # <- the last dense must have output 2

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=10)
```

1. I added a `Flatten` layer after the `Dropout` (remember to import it)
2. Since the output is (2,), you need to have the second `Dense` layer to be `Dense(2)`

If you change your output to have dimensions (1,), then put again in a `Dense(1)`, but also change the loss from `categorical_crossentropy` to `binary_crossentropy`

Comment: You are welcome! If it worked, may you accept the answer?